# Make product of variable in sass/scss

Tags: css, sass

I need to make a product between two variable in sass/scss. But when I see the compiled file I see that:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 2em * 1em;
  }
```

This is the code that generate it:

```
$h1: 2em;
@mixin setHeadingFont($smartphonePortraitFontSize:1em) {
    h1 {
        font-size: #{($h1 * #{$smartphonePortraitFontSize})};
    }

@include setHeadingFont();
```

I have also tried:

```
font-size: #{(#{$h1} * #{$smartphonePortraitFontSize})};
```

or

```
font-size: #{($h1 * $smartphonePortraitFontSize)};
```

or

```
font-size: $h1 * $smartphonePortraitFontSize;
```

or

```
font-size: #{$h1} * #{$smartphonePortraitFontSize};
```

how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you remove the "em" from `$smartphonePortraitFontSize:1em`? It would fix your problem.

Comment: but I want that users can use all units that they want not only em. Is better to leave user to select unit it's my scope @AymanSafadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find the question if someone are interested to it:

```
@function removeUnit($num) {
    @return ($num / ($num * 0 + 1));
}

@function getUnit($num){
    @return (unit($num));
}

$unit_num: getUnit($smartphonePortraitFontSize);
h1 {
     font-size: (removeUnit($h1) * removeUnit($smartphonePortraitFontSize))#{$unit_num};
}
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it! However there is already a native equivalent to `getUnit`, it's simply: [`unit($n)`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#unit-instance_method)